# Swift3 - Calculate time difference between now and date from Database

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, timestamp, dateformatter

I want to calculate time difference between now and date from Database.

What is the correct dateFormatter.dateFormat for "Fri Oct 13 2017 15:14:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)"?

Here is my code trial..

http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

```
    let input = "Fri Oct 13 2017 15:14:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)"

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    var userCalendar = Calendar.current
    userCalendar.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    let requestedComponent: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.hour,.minute,.second]
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd yyyy kk:mm:ss"
    let startTime = Date()
    let endTime = dateFormatter.date(from: input)
    let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: endTime!, to: startTime)

    print(timeDifference)

    let date = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(from: timeDifference)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    let dateString =  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

    print(dateString)
```

Thats work with:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss"
let endTime = dateFormatter.date(from: "14/10/17 11:00:00")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two timezones in your string so you will need to remove the last one and escape the 'GMT' before parsing it. Also `kk` it is used for hours from 01 to 24 what you want it is 00-23 in this case you need to use `HH`:

```
let input = "Fri Oct 13 2017 15:14:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
let dateString = input.components(separatedBy: " ").dropLast().joined(separator: " ")
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

To display the elapsed time you can use DateComponentsFormatter and use unitsStyle .positional:

```
let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(date)
let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .positional
dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: elapsedTime)   // "23:32:34"
```